# "Choco chips" for chocolate chips?

Tags: american-english, british-english, abbreviations, subcontinental-english, food

Is it alright to call chocolate chips "choco chips" in a shortened form as we do in many Asian countries. Does this sound strange or funny to native English speakers? I know "choc chip" is short for "chocolate chip" in British English.

Comment: "Choco chips" would lead someone in the US to suspect that the "chips" were not chocolate but rather some sort of imitation.

Comment: Thank you very much, Hot Licks-san. It is very helpful. TS

Comment: I am familiar with the short form _choco_ mainly from the classic Shonen Knife song, "[I Wanna Eat Chocobars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kf0WlyvR3y8)." For the most part, U.S. purveyors of ersatz chocolate steer clear of "choco" in favor of "rich chocolaty coating [or _filling_]" and the like. I have never heard a native English speaker voluntarily refer to genuine chocolate as _choco_.

Answer (score 5):

Because the US Food and Drug Act regulates how food is labeled, US consumers are used to abbreviations (like *choco*) and alternate spellings (like say, *chocko*) in the names of products that have little, if any, of the ingredient suggested.

Here's a brand of cookie called "[Choco Chip](http://www.21food.com/products/choco-chip-167183.html)", and here's the composition:

> wheat flour, margarine, sugar, egg, roombutter, cherry, cornflakes, cashews, chocolate powder

The FDA requires that ingredients be listed in descending order of amount present, so anything resembling actual chocolate in these cookies is ninth of nine ingredients.

Only the most naive of US consumers would be surprised by this.

I don't even want to know what "roombutter" is.

Comment: This is a real eye-opener. Thank you very much.

Comment: It appears that "roombutter" is "cream butter", meaning perhaps simple "butter", or perhaps "sour cream".  A word sounding like what I would spell as "rheum" is used in several European languages to mean "cream" or "sour cream".